# TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to implement some validation in a sign up system, but I get the error:

```
     TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function
```

from the following code:

```
module.exports = function(app, express) {
  var express = require('express');
  var api = express.Router();

  // post users to database
  api.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;
    var key = req.body.key;

    // Validation
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail(); 
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors) {
      res.render('register', {
        errors: errors
      });
    } else {
      var user = new User({
        email: email,
        password: password
      });
      var token = createToken(user);
    }

    // save to database
    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }

      res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'User has been created',
        token: token
      });
    });

  });
```

I've checked and it's getting the info from the front end, and I've had almost the same code work in another app (where is wasn't wrapped in module.exports = function(app, express) { }

Comment: `app.use(function(req, res, next) { req.checkBody = function(...implementation...); next() })`?

Comment: can you explain that a little more?

Comment: You must define `checkBody`/`validationErrors` in `req` before use it. You can do it inside middleware like above or attach to `app.locals` e.g. `app.locals.checkBody(req)` on application start.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to install `express-validator` using below command

```
npm install express-validator
```

then add

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
api.use(expressValidator())
```

immediately after

```
var api = express.Router();
```

See [TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function including bodyparser and expressvalidator module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583510/typeerror-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function-including-bodyparser-and-expressvalid/40584062#40584062) for more details

Answer (score 3):

With `express-validator` 6 you will have to do the following:

**import**

```
var router = express.Router();
var { body, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
```

**validation**

```
body('username').isEmail()
body('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
```

**errors**

```
const errors = validationResult(req);
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem, I found out that the problem was from the current version of express_validator. I had to degrade to   "express-validator": "5.3.1", and it worked for me.
I think the need to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same as in the above answer, after installing express-validator, adding

```
server.use(expressValidator());
```

under

```
const express=require("express");
```

and

```
const server=express();
```

solved my problem.

Comment: I did try the same, but still getting same error. Even I did checked request object there is all methods of express-validator available. But still getting error

Comment: can you post the code where u used the req.checkBody() function

Answer (score -2):

just change :

```js
noEmpty()
to
isLength({min:1})
```