# TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function including bodyparser and expressvalidator module

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, request

I'm getting error req.checkBody is not a function thought I've included express-validator and body-parser..

Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html')
});

app.post('/',function(req,res){
        req.checkBody("name", "Invalid company").notEmpty();

        var errors = req.validationErrors();
        if (errors) {
            res.status(400).send({ "message": "Missing parameter" });
            // res.send('There have been validation errors: ' + util.inspect(errors), 400);
            return;
        }
        var company = new companySchema(req.body);
        company.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 11000) {
                    return res.status(409).send({ "message": "Company already exist!" });
                }
                return res.status(400).send({ "message": "Server Error!", "err": err });
            }

            return res.status(200).send({ "message": "New company has added!" });

        });

    });

app.listen('3000');
console.log('listening on 3000!')
```

Edited part is included index.html for reference

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
 <form method = "post" action="http://localhost:3000">
    <label for="fname">Company name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="name">        
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error I am getting is

> TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function

Comment: Try to include express-validator at `index.js`.

Comment: Tried but didn't work.

Comment: @stdob-- I've just inserted function directly to check working of function but getting same error

Comment: Okay Thanks It worked by  including app.use(expressValidator());
at index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(expressValidator());  //this line to be addded

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html')
});

app.post('/',function(req,res){
        req.checkBody("name", "Invalid company").notEmpty();

        var errors = req.validationErrors();
        if (errors) {
            res.status(400).send({ "message": "Missing parameter" });
            // res.send('There have been validation errors: ' + util.inspect(errors), 400);
            return;
        }
        var company = new companySchema(req.body);
        company.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 11000) {
                    return res.status(409).send({ "message": "Company already exist!" });
                }
                return res.status(400).send({ "message": "Server Error!", "err": err });
            }

            return res.status(200).send({ "message": "New company has added!" });

        });

    });
```

Comment: I am getting similar issue, I checked req object and there is all the methods of express-validator. But when I try to call them I am getting TypeError for function is not defined