# TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function. The express-validator does not work and validation fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am defining a post route which handles a submit request. I have written the following code in my user.js route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest:'./uploads'});

router.post('/register', upload.single('profileimage'), function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;
    if(req.file){
        var profileImage = req.file.filename;
    }
    else{
        var profileImage = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

    //form validation

    req.checkBody('name', 'Name feild is reqiured').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email feild is reqiured').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email feild is reqiured').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Name feild is reqiured').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'PasswordUser feild is reqiured').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Password donot match').equals(req.body.password);
    //check Errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.render('register', {
            errors: errors
        });
        console.log(errors);
    }
    else{
        Console.log('No Errors');
    }

});
```

My app.js has express-validator already defined in it as below:

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var app = express();
app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value){
        var namespace = param.split('.')
        , root = namespace.shift()
        , formParam = root;

        while(namespace.length) {
            formParam += '[' + namespace.shift()
        }
        return{
            param: formParam,
            msg: msg,
            value: value
        };
    }
}));
```

The error **TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function** is displayed on the browser everytime I click on Submit button to test the validation. Please let me know what is missing in the code, or any amendments required.

Already gone through the below mentioned link but it did not work for me.:
[TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173907/typeerror-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function)

Comment: which file is your app's entry point?

Comment: create router in app.js file and then pass it to the users.js. you are creating second express() object, that's why app.user(expressValidator()) not working in user.js, because it's app.js' express object

Comment: @donquixote I added the below two lines and tried this as well in users.js:

`var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
router.use(expressValidator())`

But then no error is shown on webpage, but it keeps on reloading. Also, no validation message is displayed on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I've made simple app, try to rewrite your code according to this, it works fine

app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value){
        var namespace = param.split('.')
        , root = namespace.shift()
        , formParam = root;

        while(namespace.length) {
            formParam += '[' + namespace.shift()
        }
        return{
            param: formParam,
            msg: msg,
            value: value
        };
    }
}));
// I pass app to the users.js file, because express validator I've assigned 
// to this express app instance
require('./users')(app);

app.listen(3300);
```

you can skip body-parser and cors.
users.js file looks like

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
        req.checkBody('name', 'Name feild is reqiured').notEmpty();
        var errors = req.validationErrors();
        if(errors){

            res.status(400).json({"errors": errors});
        }
        else{
            Console.log('No Errors');
            res.status(200).json({"foo": "bar"});
        }
    });
};
```

I use app.post('/register'), because express router must be instantiated and if you create router to the new express object you will not have connection to the express validator, because that express validator was assigned to other express object which you created at app.js file.