# req.checkBody is not a function for express-validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-validator

I'm trying to do some basic form validation that worked before but is now throwing me an error saying req.checkBody is not a function.

I have an app.js file. In that file, I've required express validator.

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
```

I implement expressValidator in the app.js file:

```
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
        , root = namespace.shift()
        , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param: formParam,
      msg : msg,
      value : value
    }
  }
}));
```

Then, in a user.js file, I have this bit of code which is throwing the error. I do not have express-validator required in the user.js file (never needed to before and it worked fine). I export this whole thing to the app.js file.

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {

  // get user inputs
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  // form validation
  req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required.').notEmpty();

});
```

Comment: Check that `app.use(expressValidator, ...`  before `app.use(router, ...`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173907/typeerror-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function)