# express-validator error -> TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am using express-validator package to validate requested data.

[According to these answer I also did change the order or package declaration and initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173907/typeerror-req-checkbody-is-not-a-function)

below is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require('passport');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const expressJwt = require("express-jwt");
const error_staus = 404;
const morgan = require('morgan');
const logger = require('./helper/logger');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
let server = "";
const bugsnag = require('bugsnag');
// import our configurations from config/tester.js file
const config = require("./config/tester").get(process.env.NODE_ENV);
require('./helper/passport');
require("./helper/translator");

// create our Express app 
const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set("views", `${__dirname}/views`);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// serves up static files from the public folder. Anything in app/ will just be served up as the file it is
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));


// Takes the raw requests and turns them into usable properties on req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Exposes a bunch of methods for validating data. Used heavily on userController.validateRegister
app.use(expressValidator());

// Sessions allow us to store data on visitors from request to request
app.use(session({
    secret: '123456',
    key: '99785',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

app.use(session({ 
    "secret": 'secret12345', 
    "resave": false, 
    "saveUninitialized": true 
}));

// Passport JS is what we use to handle our logins
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// promisify some callback based APIs
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.login = promisify(req.login, req);
    next();
});

// begin logger
app.use(morgan('dev', {
    skip: function (req, res) {
        return res.statusCode < 400
    }, stream: process.stderr
}));

app.use(morgan('dev', {
    skip: function (req, res) {
        return res.statusCode >= 400
    }, stream: process.stdout
}));

app.use('/', routes);

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    logger.error('404 page requested');
    res.sendStatus(error_staus);
});

// done! we export it so we can start the site in start.js
module.exports = app;
```

This is the userController.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');

exports.loginForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
};

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render('register', { title: 'Register' });
};

exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
  req.sanitizeBody('name');
  req.checkBody('name', 'You must supply a name!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'That Email is not valid!').isEmail();
  req.sanitizeBody('email').normalizeEmail({
    gmail_remove_dots: false,
    remove_extension: false,
    gmail_remove_subaddress: false
  });
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password Cannot be Blank!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Confirmed Password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Oops! Your passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

  const errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    req.flash('error', errors.map(err => err.msg));
    res.render('register', { title: 'Register', body: req.body, flashes: req.flash() });
    return; // stop the fn from running
  }
  next(); // there were no errors!
};
```

Note : I am using express-validator version 3.1.2

When I check request object, in that object there is all methods of express-validator too.

But try to use that method I am getting req.checkBody is not a function error.

Can anybody help with these issue ?

Comment: There simply isn't enough information here to provide much assistance, can you post the code you're experiencing this problem with?

Comment: You need to post the code. Also, you should **not** be using `req.checkBody`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator#legacy-api

Comment: @John   I have updated the Question with code